# problemas en operaciones con R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una base de datos csv2, cuando la importo,defino la variable de interés como as.character primero para luego convertirla a as.numeric de la siguiente forma:

```
options(digits = 2)
y=as.character(precip)
precipi=as.numeric(y)
```

luego armo el data frame

```
df=data.frame(cod,dmy(fecha2),precipi)
  colnames(df)= c("codigo","fech","lluvia")
```

agrego año y mes para luego agrupar

```
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(anio=year(fech)) %>%
      mutate(mes=month(fech))
```

Agrupo por año y codigo. Sumo para cada año y estacion

```
df.anual <- df %>%
  group_by(anio,codigo) %>% 
  summarise(precip.anual = sum(lluvia,na.rm="TRUE"))
```

ó

```
df.anual <- df %>%
    group_by(anio,codigo) %>% 
    summarise(precip.anual = ifelse(all(is.na(lluvia)), NA, sum(lluvia,na.rm=TRUE)))
```

El problema es el siguiente, el resultado de view(df.anual) muestra la suma para algunos años como 0 sin embargo en la base de datos original en formato csv2 para esos años hay valores que sumados deberían dar un número mayor a 0. 
Pensé que era por la presencia de NA pero arreglando esto continua el problema, en lugar de resultar 0 imprime NA pero debería imprimir un número mayor a 0.
Dejo un link para que descarguen la base de datos:
https://transfernow.net/ddl/base_precipitaciones

Comment: Kev, si hay problemas en la importación, generalmente se terminan arrastrando a todo el workflow. No entiendo por que pasas a texto y luego a numérico. ¿Tal vez por que por defecto la variable termina siendo un `factor`? Esto es señal que la importación no está reconociendo adecuadamente los valores numéricos. ¿podrías compartir el CSV o una muestra de los datos y el código que usas para importar?

Comment: Si puedo compartirle el csv, cómo se lo envío ?

Comment: Si pudieras detectar que filas son las problematicas, simplemente pegas solo estas. Sino para compartir el CSV podrías pegarlo en https://pastebin.com/ y compartir el enlace que generes

Comment: https://transfernow.net/ddl/base_precipitaciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo que has compartido es muy particular, de ninguna forma es un `csv`, no tiene ningún caracter que pueda ser considerado como separador. Pareciera ser algún tipo de reporte. La única forma que veo, puedas importarlo adecuadamente, es tratándolo como un archivo de columnas de longitud fija. R tiene [`read.fwf()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html) que sirve para leer este tipo de archivos:

```
df <- read.fwf("EXP_DATOS.txt", 
               skip = 1,
               widths = c(8, 9, 6, 6, 7), 
               n = 100000, 
               col.names = c('cod', 'fecha', 'tem', 'temp', 'precip'),
               stringsAsFactor = FALSE,
               buffersize = 200000
               )
```

- Con `skip=1` ignoramos la primer línea con los encabezados
- Con `widths` establecemos los anchos de cada columna
- Con `n = 100000` importamos las primeras 100.000 líneas (mi equipo es bastante modesto) si quieres importar el más de un millón de filas, elimina el parámetro o `n = -1`
- `buffersize = 200000` establecemos un buffer intermedio de 200kb. Para minimizar el acceso a disco.

La particularidad de esta rutina, es que además logra interpretar el tipo de dato y termina retornando un `data.frame` con todos valores numéricos y `NA` dónde no hay valor. Al menos con los primeros 100.000 registro me ha funcionado adecuadamente.